# The screen is not navigating even the click() method is executed successfully in mobile web app using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, iphone-web-app

I was trying to click a button on my mobile web app, using selenium web driver. The button is located, the text over the button can be derived and even the click event is performing well. But the navigation doesn't occur.

I tried with Click() method, sendKeys() method and also with script executor. But couldn't process further on.

**CODE:**

```
public class TestWeb
{  

    WebDriver driver; 

    private Selenium selenium;   

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
      driver = new IPhoneDriver();
      driver.get("http://10.5.95.25/mobilebanking");       
    }

    @Test
    public void TC() throws Exception  { 
        System.out.println("page 1");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement editbtn1 = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-comp-1018"));
        String s1 = editbtn1.getText();
        System.out.println(s1);
        editbtn1.click();
        editbtn1.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click;", editbtn1); 

        System.out.println("ok");
    }

@After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
         System.out.println("*******Execution Over***********");
    }
}
```

I tried click, sendKeys and ScriptExecutor separately and also combined. It is executing without any error but the navigation doesn't occur.

Does anybody can help me with some other ways to perform click function on the button?

---

Ram

Comment: The element with `id="ext-comp-1018"` is an `input` element, or any other element with some `onclick` function bound?

Comment: <div id="ext-comp-1018" class="x-button x-button-action"><span class="x-button-label" id="ext-gen1045">Login</span></div>

This is the actual code for the particular button

Comment: What would happen if you tried clicking the underlying `span` element? I know WebDriver clicks the center of the element by default, so clicking the `div` _should_ work, but ... there are some strange things happening sometimes in the world of HTML, JS, different web frameworks, WebDriver, different browsers, different OSes...

Answer (score 1):

This may not be your issue but I noticed "ext-comp-" and guess you are using extjs.

I'm using GXT and while finding by id worked for many things, on some submit buttons it didn't.

I had to use firebug in firefox to locate the element and copy the xpath.
Then I could click the element by

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='LOGIN_SUBMIT']/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div")).click();  // worked
```

It was failing silently for me too.  My submit button has the id of LOGIN_SUBMIT so I don't know why the following failed but ....

```
driver.findElement(By.id("LOGIN_SUBMIT")).click();//failed
```

Edit:

**Here is an exact example (case 1 of 2):**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='gwt-debug-LOGIN_SUBMIT']")));
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.id("gwt-debug-LOGIN_SUBMIT"))));  <!-- id works as well
```

OK so the element is found.  It will timeout and throw an exception if it is not.

Still, the following fails (under firefox, works with chrome) with no error and the page does not navigate.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gwt-debug-LOGIN_SUBMIT']")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.id("gwt-debug-LOGIN_SUBMIT")).click(); <-- fails too
```

What I have to do is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gwt-debug-LOGIN_SUBMIT']/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div")).click();
```

So my experience was that even if I found the element with xpath, clicking failed unless I used a complete xpath.

**Here is another exact example (case 2 of 2):**

I can find an element like so:

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"text" + i + "\"]"));
```

I know I have found it because I can see the text via:

```
 we.getText();
```

Still selecting by the path I found it fails.

```
//get outta town man the following fails
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"text" + i + "\"]")).click();
```

In this case there is not more explicit xpath to try as in case 1
What I had to do was use css:

```
//bingo baby works fine
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#text" + i + ".myChoices")).click();
```

Actually, I obtained the css path via firebug than shortened it.

```
//this is what I recieved
html.ext-strict body.ext-gecko div#x-auto-0.x-component div#x-auto-1.x-component div#x-auto-3..myBlank div#choicePanel1.myBlank div.x-box-inner div#text3.myChoices  //text3 is the id of the element I wanted to select
```

Whether or not you can figure out your needed xpaths and css selectors, I don't know, but I believe I experienced exactly what you did.

Comment: I have used xPath, className and ID to find the element and Click the same. No failure message has been displayed for any of the thing. The execution was successful. It finds the element, but the issue is it is not navigating when the click event is performed.

Comment: Are you on Android?  If so, have you looked at the adb logcat output ()?  There may be something going on that you can see there.  I had that happen with the local database.  The junit test wasn't telling me why it stopped but logcat showed errors specific to the android browser as run through the apk.

Comment: @Koormathi You say "The execution was successful" but I do not believe that to be the case.  Perhaps it should have been successful but not what I experienced.  I think you found the element and clicked it but it was never clicked and that if you find the element in another way, that the click may succeed.  That is what I found via my tests anyway.