# RemoteWebDriver(Firefox) doesn't work with xpath

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use RemoteWebDriver with xpath locators on google.com, this is the log from node running firefox. It receives all those commands but doesn't executes them. I dont see any activity with browser, other than opening google homepage.

Comment: Could you please post us your exact code so we could try to reproduce it? The framework is obviously used by thousands of people every day and is not therefore so blatantly broken...

Comment: Sure... my bad. Will add the code in 5 minutes.

Comment: `//*[id='gbqfq']` is invalid, it should be `//*[@id='gbqfq']`.

Comment: Anyway, if that was not the issue: Both expressions should return the same element, that is indeed strange. However, have you tried `By.xpath("//*[@name='q']")` or `By.id("gbqfq")` or `By.xpath("id('gbqfq')")`? I wonder how those would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar trouble.  Mine was with webdriver though.  I noticed the behavior depended on the browser.  In the link below I gave two examples.  The first was for firefox like you and the second was using the  android driver.  They both worked with chrome though.

In my cases xpath did finally work using a more explicit path (more explicit than needed to find the element) and if that was not possible I had so go another route like css.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11341946/1258245

Comment: This might help.. let me try.

Comment: I tried with css.. even that works. But I have all my locators as xpath.